# How to post LINE Rich menu from Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We would like to know how we could share the LINE Rich menu with specific users within the journey builder itself. We couldn't find an option in Group Connect.

Comment: By "LINE Rich menu" do you mean the option to input a Line Message Activity within the Journey Builder? In other words, do you only want certain users to have that access?

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7, Actually our requirement is to add the line feature called Rich menu (https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/using-rich-menus/#using-rich-menus-introduction), which would be displayed at the bottom of the LINE channel subscribed by users. Do you have any idea how we can assign a rich menu to the followers through Journey builder?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as you're limited with the content Journey Builder can append to a Line Message. BUT,  if anyone would know it would be @Gortonington

Comment: I got the same feeling when I searched the web. But would like to know if it is not possible in journey builder for sure.
@Gortonington, please share your thoughts on the above.